# in_app_purchases using flutter

Tags: flutter, google-play, google-play-services

I am trying to create an application that can handle In App Purchases Using Flutter.I am using the in_app_purchase 0.2.1 plugin .I have managed to setup my product on google play developer console as required but however when try to retrieve it from the application i am able to connect to the store successfully but i am not able to retrieve my product ,it always shows up as product not found.

I have followed a this tutorial https://joebirch.co/2019/05/31/adding-in-app-purchases-to-flutter-apps/  and also looked at the package documentation https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase.
My google play setup for the product is shown below
[google play console setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNDsP.png)
[google play console setup2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVvU6.png)

The function i am using is shown below.

```
  Future<List<ProductDetails>> retrieveProducts() async {
final bool available = await InAppPurchaseConnection.instance.isAvailable();
if (!available) {
  // Handle store not available
  print("Store Temporarily Unavailable");
  return null;
} else {
  print("Store Temporarily Available");
  const Set<String> _kIds = {'airtime123'};
  final ProductDetailsResponse response =
      await InAppPurchaseConnection.instance.queryProductDetails(_kIds);
  if (response.notFoundIDs.isNotEmpty) {
    print("product not found");
    print(response.notFoundIDs[0]);
    return null;
  }
  print("product found");
  return response.productDetails;
}
```

}

This is the result i get

```
I/flutter ( 7254): Store Temporarily Available
I/flutter ( 7254): product not found

I/flutter ( 7254): airtime123
```

Comment: Same problem, did you find any solution?

Comment: No not as yet unfortunately

Comment: I'm facing the same problem as 09/2020, the only solution for me is to reload the view.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a reserved SKU for the test: android.test.purchased

```
const Set<String> _kIds = {'android.test.purchased'};
final ProductDetailsResponse response =
    await InAppPurchaseConnection.instance.queryProductDetails(_kIds);
```

Comment: Yes, but we need a product which is not purchased yet.

Comment: You may use 'android.test.canceled' instead. https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing

Comment: But we need to test on real ids.